# Error reading signed content when installing SonarLint in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, sonarlint

In Windows 10 Pro and Eclipse 4.22 I'm trying to install SonarLint 7.8 (also tried 7.4 and 3.6) and I get this error message (Marketplace and manual installation give me the same message):

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
> session context was:(profile=DefaultProfile, >phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
> Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.squareup.okhttp3,4.10.0.
> Error reading signed >content:C:\Users\ABCABC~1.ABA\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile2582698948173464480.jar
> An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: >C:\Users\ABCABC~1.ABA\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile2582698948173464480.jar

The file exists and I can open it with 7-zip so it's not a file corruption issue.

Tryied removing the file and then the same error message referencing another jar file arises.

Any idea about what the problem can be?

Comment: Your Eclipse is pretty outdated (five releases behind). Please upgrade.

Comment: @howlger It is a corporative machine and I can't update Eclipse. I hope there is another solution.

Comment: Installing plugins and updating is technically the same, so you can. Stop wasting time and upgrade. Please make sure that the software you are using is up to date before asking.

Comment: @howlger I can't update Eclipse, my machine have a security audit software that detects software/versions not allowed by the company. SonarLint is allowed. If there is an option to install SonarLint I would like to try it.

Comment: @howlger I guess you would go crazy knowing how many companies works this way. If it works don't touch it.

Comment: If there would be something that would drive me crazy, it would be wasting time making things more insecure in the name of security. You ask how to install a plugin whose signature verification failed, which ensures that the plugin has not been modified. Probably your Eclipse is too old to be able to verify the signature. Eclipse itself consists of plugins. If you can install plugins, you should also be able to use an up-to-date Eclipse. But better get rid of your company's anti-security policy (this would be a good example to explain it to others as SonarLint is also about security).

Comment: @howlger we all know that. In the real world I have an issue I would like to solve if possible. If not possible I will forget about SonerLint in this project.

Comment: You can just [download latest Eclipse as ZIP](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/), unzip it and run it. It does not need to be installed into `C:\Program Files` or access the Windows registry. If `eclipse.exe` will be blocked, run it directly as Java application. Talk to the person in charge of this anti-security policy and explain the problem. Nowadays you really need to protect your supply chain because there is a real risk. See/watch e.g. https://youtu.be/UMLfEL9YqEE